# My mantaflow fluid simulation is going the wrong way

Tags: fluid-simulation

so i am working on this project, and my fluid seems to think that the y axis is the x axis?? the fluid flows to the wall instead of the floor, like as if gravity has flipped[image]

Comment: X and Y are sideways, Z is up and down. If this is what you expected but it’s not happening, check the scene properties tab to see if gravity has been changed.